# Cordova Open PDF in aplication dosn't work Android

Tags: android, cordova, pdf

I've a problem with open PDF file in my application. I use href on button and windows.open. In browser (chrome) it works.  On android not work. How do I set my PDF files opened in the application.

```
<script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/design.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() { 
          $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({  
          type: "GET",  
          url: "http://url adres",  
          dataType: "xml",
          crossDomain: true, 
          success: parseXml  
                });  
                function parseXml(xml) 
                {
                  $(xml).find("download").each(function() {
                    $(this).find("item").each(function() {
                       $("#pobieranie").append('<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" href="'+$(this).find('plik').text()+'" id="products">'+$(this).find('name').text()+'</a></div></div></div><br/>');  
                    });
                  });
                  window.open("http://urladres.pdf", "_system", "location=yes");
                } 
            }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: have you installed inAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: Thanks i install and this work. Thaks